# Tweepy streaming API: filtering on user

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to simply connect to the `Twitter streaming API` using `tweepy` (and python 3), and stream all tweets from a given single user.

I was under the impression this is possible, so I have the following simple code to do this:

```py
from tweepy import StreamListener
from tweepy import Stream
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        # process stream data here
        print(data)

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener = StdOutListener()
    twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener)
    twitterStream.filter(follow=['575930104'])
```

When I run this from the command line, I just get back a bunch of 406 codes from Twitter. Is there something very obviously wrong with how I am trying to use tweepy, or is the "follow" parameter not designed to do what I think it does?

**EDIT:** I've also posted [this](http://discuss.tweepy.org/t/streaming-api-filtering-on-user/208) on the tweepy discussion boards, FYI.

Comment: Also, what version of `tweepy` do you have installed (use `pip show tweepy`); I tested with 3.3.0.

Comment: I have version 3.2.0 and I'm on python 3.4. Maybe I should upgrade to 3.3.0. Let me try this and see what happens.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just upgraded to 3.3.0 and now it works fine. I presume it was a bug in 3.2.0. Possibly related to the one discussed here? http://discuss.tweepy.org/t/filtering-hangs-in-python-3/194

Thanks for pointing out that there was a new version... didn't see it. If you make it an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: Ah, the trick was trying this with Python 3.4 instead of 2.7. Reproduced with 3.2.0, fixed with 3.3.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem on Python 3.4 using Tweepy 3.2.0. Upgrading to 3.3.0 solved the problem:

```
$ bin/pip install -U tweepy==3.2.0
[...]
Successfully installed tweepy requests-oauthlib six requests
Cleaning up...
$ bin/python test.py 
406
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
[...]
KeyboardInterrupt
$ bin/pip install -U tweepy==3.3.0
[...]
Successfully installed tweepy requests requests-oauthlib six
Cleaning up...
$ bin/python test.py
{"created_at":"Fri Feb 27 14:02:02 +0000 2015","id":571309283217768448,"id_str":"571309283217768448",
[...]
```

The [Tweepy 3.3.0 Changelog](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/v3.3.0/CHANGELOG.md) mentions several streaming improvements, although I did not see the 'freezing' problem they mention.

Comment: Hi on Tweppy 3.3.0 I have the 406 response if I use `stream.filter(follow=['@atm_informa'])` . All is ok if I use `stream.filter(follow=['575930104'])` . What is the relation between the code and the user name? Thanks

Comment: @franco_b: sorry, I don't know.

Comment: http://gettwitterid.com/?user_name=atm_informa&submit=GET+USER+ID give the relation between user_name and user_id